# Express routing not matching url

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have an express route that I want to find a uid value and for some reason it isn't working I was wondering what I was doing wrong. I keep getting an error whenever I got to localhost:8080/user?uid=20 and I want to retrieve 20 as the param uid but keep getting an error.

My path
/user?uid=:uid\d+

The code itself

```
router.get('/user\?uid=:uid\d+', (req,res) => {

    res.send('This works');
});
```

Comment: Are you getting an actual error? if so what is it? Or are your routes just not matching?

Comment: The route just wasn't matching and would keep returning an error. Zeitgeist solution worked though and I'm going to read more on it

Answer (score 1):

Having a regex patter for catching query string is not a good practice. Reduce your route to `/user`, then you can have access to your query strings through `req`, just like this:

for `localhost:3000/user?uuid=20`

```
router.get('/user', (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.query); // { uuid: 20 }
    console.log(req.query.uuid); // 20

    res.send('This works');
});
```

You can have more information here: https://expressjs.com/es/api.html#req.query